# Using vertex_name when reading a GraphML file with Boost Graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I am trying to load a simple GraphML file such that each vertex has a vertex name as stored in the GraphML. I can change the GraphML, the important thing is that I have access to the vertex_name from code afterwards.

Here's the most minimal example that I could extract that still shows the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS,property<vertex_name_t,std::string> > BoostGraphType;
    typedef dynamic_properties BoostDynamicProperties;

    std::string fn = "simple.graphml";
    std::ifstream is(fn.c_str()); 
    if (!is.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "loading file '" << fn << "'failed." << std::endl;
        throw "Could not load file.";
    }

    BoostGraphType g;
    BoostDynamicProperties dp ;
    const std::string vn = "vertex_name";
    dp.property(vn,get(vertex_name,g));
    read_graphml(is, g, dp);

    for (auto vp = vertices(g); vp.first != vp.second; ++vp.first)
    {
        std::cout << "index '" << get(vertex_index,g,*vp.first) << "' ";
        std::cout << "name '" << get(vertex_name,g,*vp.first) << "'"
        << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am using the the following GraphML test file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
    http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
  <key id="d0" for="node" attr.name="vertex_name" attr.type="string"/>
  <graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
    <node id="A"> <data key="d0">A</data> </node>
    <node id="B"> <data key="d0">B</data> </node>
    <edge id="0" source="A" target="B"/>
   </graph>
</graphml>
```

read_graphml throws an exception with the helpful message (e.what()):

```
 parse error: unrecognized type "
```

It seems the problem is related to the vertex_name association (which I got from a comment to a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433492/boost-graph-read-graphml-dynamic-vertex-properties)).

If I remove

```
<data key="d0">A</data>
```

from the node, it works.

However, I need to be able to identify the vertices by vertex_name.

How can I fix this so it properly parses the graphml and does not throw? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try it on basic sample GraphML from Wikipedia -http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphML. You will know if the error is related to malformed file.

Comment: I think the problem is partially related to a mal-formed file, but I cannot find out what exactly I am doing wrong. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly when I run it.

```
>wilbert.exe
index '0' name 'A'
index '1' name 'B'
```

This is using boost v1.52 on windows 7

Comment: I tried it on windows, using boost 1.53. What OS and boost are you using?